# define array key values outside pg_fetch_array

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

I basically want to define the `$georesults` array and its key value pairs outside the while loop, but I want the array to be populated by the rows from `pg_fetch_array()` inside the while loop.

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $georesults['results'][] = array(
                    "$columns[0]" => $row["$columns[0]"],
                    "$columns[1]" => $row["$columns[1]"],
                    "$columns[2]" => $row["$columns[2]"],
                    "$columns[3]" => $row["$columns[3]"]
                    );
    }
```

I am not quite sure how to achieve this.

Is it possible to define the array:

```
$georesults['results'][] = array(
                    "$columns[0]" => $row["$columns[0]"],
                    "$columns[1]" => $row["$columns[1]"],
                    "$columns[2]" => $row["$columns[2]"],
                    "$columns[3]" => $row["$columns[3]"]
                    );
```

outside of the while loop but have it populated from results of `pg_fetch_array`?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to dynamically set the number of key value pairs depending on the columns defined in a query. The query will change often. Depending on what is selected by the user.

Regards
Geo

Answer (score 1):

//Declare the array variable outside the loop.

```
 $results=array();

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

        $results[] = $row;
    }
//you can use the result outside the loop.

or

    $results=array();

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result, NULL, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {

      $results[] = array('id'=>$row['id'],'name'=>$row['name'], 'password'=>$row['password'] );

    }

//use the result outside the loop
```

hope it helps

Comment: I realised that all i need to do was use pg_fetch_all() instead of pg_fetch_array(), which returns the columns specified in the query.